# referencing the cell which returns empty cell in its formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula which I calculate the minimum value in Sheet2 in a dynamic range

```
 =IF(MIN(I21:INDEX(I:I;MIN(IF(A21:A108="";ROW(A21:A108)))))=0;"";MIN(I21:INDEX(I:I;MIN(IF(A21:A108="";ROW(A21:A108))))))
```

and I have following formula which returns the cell I20 of Sheet2(which my above formula is inside)

```
 =WEEKNUM(Sheet2!I20)
```

When I20 does not return any value my Weeknum formula returns #VALUE! and i want it to return only if there is a value in I20 and if there is no value in I20 then i want it to return empty.

How can i do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=IFERROR(WEEKNUM(Sheet2!I20),"")
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the error, use `IFERROR`

`=IFERROR(IF(MIN(I21:INDEX(I:I;MIN(IF(A21:A108="";ROW(A21:A108)))))=0;"";MIN(I21:INDEX(I:I;MIN(IF(A21:A108="";ROW(A21:A108)))))),"")`

Comment: No, this does not solve my problem, still i see VALUE#!

Comment: tested the formula, and it works fine. Not sure how you solved it, but the `IFERROR` will handle what ever error you shold get between.

Comment: do you mean i should write this instead of my formula in Sheet2? Because the error i receive is in another sheet called Sheet1 where i reference Sheet2 value `=WEEKNUM(Sheet2!I20) ` which has a formula `=IF(MIN(I21:INDEX(I:I;MIN(IF(A21:A108="";ROW(A21:A108)))))=0;"";MIN(I21:INDEX(I:I;MIN(IF(A21:A108="";ROW(A21:A108))))))`

Comment: now i got the right answer. you were right with iferror but only the cell i should use was the different one. thanks!